# Solr wildcard search not working on general text field

Tags: solr

Am new to Solr world and I have Solr 7.7.2

Am trying to do a wild card search and it is not returning any results. Given below is my index, query analyzer set up for the field type.

Sample text:
Solr’s standard query parser supports single and multiple character wildcard searches within single terms.

In the above sample text, I would like to search for **standar*** to match the word **standard** Appreciate your help on this.

---

```html
<fieldType name="text_general" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100" multiValued="true">
    <analyzer type="index">
      <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>      
      <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.txt" />
      <filter class="solr.SynonymGraphFilterFactory" synonyms="synonyms.txt" ignoreCase="true" expand="true"/>
      <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterGraphFilterFactory" preserveOriginal="1" splitOnCaseChange="0" splitOnNumerics="0"/>
      <filter class="solr.FlattenGraphFilterFactory" />
      <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterGraphFilterFactory" preserveOriginal="1"/>
      <filter class="solr.FlattenGraphFilterFactory" />
      <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
      <filter class="solr.PorterStemFilterFactory"/>
      <filter class="solr.RemoveDuplicatesTokenFilterFactory" />
    </analyzer>
    <analyzer type="query">
      <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>      
      <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.txt" />
      <filter class="solr.SynonymGraphFilterFactory" synonyms="synonyms.txt" ignoreCase="true" expand="true"/>
      <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterGraphFilterFactory" preserveOriginal="1" splitOnCaseChange="0" splitOnNumerics="0"/>
      <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
      <filter class="solr.PorterStemFilterFactory"/>
      <filter class="solr.RemoveDuplicatesTokenFilterFactory" />
    </analyzer>
  </fieldType>
```

[image: Analysis screen shot from admin page]

Comment: the wildcard will work on the string field and not on the text field

Comment: Hi Abhijith, thanks for your reply. But simple string field type also not working. **standard** on Field Value (Index) and **standar*** on Field Value (Query) doesn't match.

Comment: you need to restart the server after changes...

Comment: I have not changed the field type. Just using the Analysis  screen in the admin portal and trying to check by selecting the field as **string** and run above

Comment: You can't use the analysis screen to see how wildcard searches are performed; the analysis page will show how a literal value of `standard*` would be parsed (since analysis doesn't really happen for wildcard queries), not how a wildcard query would be matched. Also be aware that a wildcard search needs to match the _whole_ token, and that analysis _does not happen_ (except for only multitermaware filters) when a wildcard query is made, so you usually don't get the input processed as you'd expect.

Comment: Okay, thanks @MatsLindh. Any suggestions on my original query?

Comment: It depends. What text do you want to index and how do you want to match it? If `standard` is a word in the text (i.e. `this is standard`, having only a WhitespaceTokenizer and a lowercase filter should allow you to do `field:standar*` to match the single `standard` token. For more advanced processing an NgramFilter will be required

Answer (score 0):

After few more hours of analyzing,  added EdgeNgramfilter and it worked.
I guess there will be performance issues if used on the large text field. I may need to test it out.

```html
<filter class="solr.EdgeNGramFilterFactory" minGramSize="5" maxGramSize="10"/>
```

```html
<analyzer type="index">
      <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>      
      <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.txt" />
      <filter class="solr.SynonymGraphFilterFactory" synonyms="synonyms.txt" ignoreCase="true" expand="true"/>
      <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterGraphFilterFactory" preserveOriginal="1" splitOnCaseChange="0" splitOnNumerics="0"/>
      <filter class="solr.FlattenGraphFilterFactory" />
      <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterGraphFilterFactory" preserveOriginal="1"/>
      <filter class="solr.FlattenGraphFilterFactory" />
      <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
      <filter class="solr.EdgeNGramFilterFactory" minGramSize="5" maxGramSize="10"/>
      <filter class="solr.PorterStemFilterFactory"/>
      <filter class="solr.RemoveDuplicatesTokenFilterFactory" />
</analyzer>
```